# Seeking shapefile of all Montreal Neighborhoods

Tags: shapefile, data, canada

I am trying to map out Montreal and was wondering if there is already an existing polygon shapefile of all the neighborhoods.  Here is a link to a perfect example of what I am looking for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:ArrondissementsQuartiersMontreal.svg&page=1

If I can get that in shapefile format, it would save me a lot of time!

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have two ideas:

1. Check out the [Statistics Canada](http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2011-eng.cfm) site for .shp downloads.  It
   looks like "Census Subdivisions" is what you are after, although
   there may be more detailed products there.
2. An alternative is to use the ArcGIS basemaps in ArcMap (File > Add
   Data > Add Base Map > National Geographic).  These are great for
   displaying down to the street level in detail (including
   neighborhoods)

[image]

Comment: In this data is everything but neighborhoods. Look at your map at google: "Kirkland" ("Kirkland is an on-island suburb on the Island of Montreal in southwestern Quebec, Canada.") - google description. It lays probably by Pierrefonds - which is neighborhood - and not found in this data. And so on...

Answer (score 2):

Directly from the City of Montreal website, the borough (arrondissements) polygons are available in different formats [here](http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/polygones-arrondissements).

Answer (score 1):

Some open-data options:

Flickr Shapefiles: http://code.flickr.net/2011/01/08/flickr-shapefiles-public-dataset-2-0/

OpenStreetMap Metro Extracts: http://metro.teczno.com/

Answer (score 0):

Commercial provider [Maponics](http://www.maponics.com/neighborhood-boundaries) has well over 100 neighborhoods for Montreal.

Answer (score 0):

Polygons delimiting the boroughs of the City of Montreal, boroughs and related cities constituting the agglomeration of Montreal.

Format and field names in accordance with the open data standardization work of Quebec municipalities.

https://donnees.montreal.ca/ville-de-montreal/polygones-arrondissements

Answer (score -1):

I found this boroughs shapefile of the Montreal 2016 boroughs through ESRI:

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7422af60f3534943bf28b0a12962ce92

If you are planning on grabbing the shapefile, click "Open in ArcGIS Desktop" then "Open in ArcMap".  I exported the whole shapefile into a new shapefile and it's manageable.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest https://www.donneesquebec.ca/  look for "Arrondissements" or "Quartiers" or "Quartiers sociologiques" or "Découpage administratif"  in the search bar, you will find  neighborhoods polygon maps for montreal and other quebec cities.

[image: Arrondissements et Villes liées]